# Error using databinding in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, data-binding

I am trying to test data binding as given in the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html). 
I have included this in my build.gradle file (of module app) :

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc2'
```

In the project build.gradle file, I have included this in my dependencies :

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta2"
classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0"
```

The layout file is exactly the same as the one given in the guide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
   <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@{user.firstName}"/>
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@{user.lastName}"/>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Initially it gave an error `Element layout does not have the required attribute layout_width and layout_height`.

I tried to fix it by assigning match_parent to both. Then I got the error
`Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute` on the lines where i assigned `layout_height` and `layout_width` to the linear layout.

Again I tried to fix this by removing these attributes. Now every time I try to compile, I see this- `error: package my.package.name.databinding` does not exist.

The code completion is working perfectly in my Fragment where I am trying to use this layout.

So what did I miss ?

Comment: can you post your `user` POJO class and `Activity` class

Comment: Double check package reference in the xml `type` attribute. `my.package.User` or `com.example.User`

Comment: I ran into this error and finally discovered it was because I had a duplicated android xml namespace. The DataBinding library in Android Studio is reeeeaaaally bad about letting you know where the problem is right now. Hopefully the next update will clear things up.

Comment: You can also check [this](http://chintanrathod.com/develop_apps_faster_using_data_binding_part2/) tutorial for your reference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

removing `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'` from my build.gradle solved my problem.

Comment: Same here, I believe data-binding already uses apt internally. If you're using dagger or any other apt-dependent library just use provided "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1" instead of apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1"

Comment: for me the problem was `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'` upgrading to 1.8 solved the issue

Comment: if anybody cares, you can ready why @miv has the right answer here: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issues/38/android-apt-breaks-brand-new-data-binding

Comment: I'm getting `NPA` in `butterknife `@BindView`` after removing this `apt` stuff

Comment: @sakirk could you help me on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39837222/6599627

Answer (score 20):

Your bindings in the xml file might be invalid.

Make sure to double check

1. Are `type` attributes valid reference to data object? `type="my.package.Class"`
2. Are the binding valid? `name="client"` -> `"@{client.field}"`
3. Are data fields accessible? `public` or encapsulated with getters
4. Are field names in java and the xml file matching, check for typos
5. If you have renamed the xml file, make sure you also update the Binding objects. `OldNameBinding -> NewNameBinding`
6. Clean Project

Comment: I recently renamed a package and Android Studio kept looking for 'com.oldpackage.app.databinding..' despite cleaning of project. Restarting A.Studio did the trick though.

Comment: Perfect checklist, thanks, worked for me (left incorrect binding after copy-paste from the net)

Comment: Between 3 and 4 I would add "Check for typos and mismatches in the field/getter names and the names used in the XML." That was the case for me. The incorrect was grayed out as unused in the java file.

Comment: It's obvious in hindsight, but for the `BaseObservable`/Data class to be accessible to the `databinding` package, fields/setters must be `public`.

Comment: A single error in one XML layout file can cause the same error for all XML layout files using data binding in a package even all other layout files are flawless.

Answer (score 3):

it’s usually because there is an error in your XML layout file and it can’t generate the binding object. Make sure you write data type correctly, check lower or upper of your writing.

```
    <data>
        <variable name="yourObject" type="com.example.simple.YourObject"/>
    </data>
```

And make sure object is right calling:

```
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{yourObject.name}"/>
    <TextView
```

Comment: After searching for a while, I found this post.  I finally commented out most of my XML file and then the error went away.  From there, I was able to debug the issue that was in fact in my xml (that I was not seeing in the compiler output), and was causing the error for *"Can't find databinding package"*.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue in android studio. The editor will flag it as an error however it will still compile.

I had the same issue and so I cloned this example repo to test my system is configured correctly to support the databinding api https://github.com/mgrzechocinski/android-bindings-example

Ignore the error warning on the `layout` tag. It is wrong.

Something I noticed is you don't necessarily require the `data` tag if are simply using the databinding to get access to the views items through the BindingActivity class that is generated.

Comment: You don't NEED the `data` tag??  This article says otherwise! https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

Comment: You do not need the data tag if you only want to take advantage of the BindingActivity that is generated by the plugin. Ie MainActivityBinding.myview

Comment: @Alec He does need the data tag, as he's clearly going to use the setUser() method on the generated class and set the data in the layout automatically. Also, you can use the data tag to set the generated class name, i.e. `<data name="UserData"></data>` and then the generated class will be UserData rather than LayoutNameBinding.

To say he doesn't NEED the data tag ignores it's uses and what you gain by using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 'android-apt' plugin for dagger or other libraries, after enabling data binding, you have to remove 'android-apt' plugin and use 'provided' instead of 'apt' in your dependencies. For example if you are using dagger, remove this

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
```

and this

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

and then replace

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
```

with

```
provided 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [current version](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) of the guide (2015-11-11) you just have to add two dependencies:
In the file build.gradle of the project add the gradle dependency. Currently the most recent [version](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/) is 1.5.0-beta3

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta3'
    }
```

And in the file build.gradle of the module include the dataBinding section:

```
android{
  ...
  dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
  ...
}
```

The error

> error: package my.package.name.databinding does not exists

may ocurr because a mismatch between the xml and the POJO class

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful that your POJO class data members should be `public` if you are not creating the getter setters.

If you have simple POJO without any getter or setter

```
public class User {
   public final String firstName;
   public final String lastName;
   public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }
}
```

If you make getter setter, javaBean style class

```
public class User {
   private final String firstName;
   private final String lastName;
   public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
       return this.firstName;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
       return this.lastName;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was adding `layout_height` and `layout_width` to the `layout` tag and also to my root layout. I've just removed both attributes from the `layout` tag and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem or mismatch between your model and your layout file. In my case I had:

```
...
<TextView
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/photo"
            tools:text="0912454433"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@{contact.cellPhoneNumber}"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

but my model class was like so:

```
public class MyContact {
    public String name;
    public String cellphoneNumber; // <-- Notice the lowercase 'p'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you forgot to add data binding plugin to your app's gradle file:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'`

You have to apply it to any module you want to use data binding.

Also, you should not add layout_w/h to the `layout` tag, it is just an Android Studio bug, already fixed in aosp.

Comment: This isn't necessarily the solution.  I have `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding`, and am still getting this error.

Comment: Are you using Android-apt?

Comment: Where exactly should I use `apt` in regards to databinding?

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'` is no longer necessary

Answer (score -1):

I also suffer with the same problem. But my mistake is

User class variables declared as not a public. So we should declare the POJO class variables as public.

```
public class User {


    public String firstName,lastName;

        public User(String fname,String lname){
            this.firstName=fname;
            this.lastName=lname;
        }
    }
```

Then solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

// This is under activity_main xml .

```
  <data>
  <variable
      name="student"
      type="com.example.vishalkamboj.testdatabinding.Student"    />
</data>
```

// This is Student Class

```
public class Student {
```

public  String firstname ;
public String lastname ;

```
public Student(String firstname , String lastname)
{
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;

}
```

}