# Android Data Binding XML Error

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I'm using Data Binding Library on a Android Studio Project when whenever I build, run, clean, rebuild, etc I get the following error:

```
 :app:processDebugResources AGPBI:

{"kind":"error","text":"Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute","sources": [{"file":"C:\\Users\\lucia.beltran\\Desktop\\Picho\\Projects\\Personal\\ improved-tribble\\ImprovedTribble\\app\\build\\intermediates\\data-binding-layout-out\\debug\\ layout\\task_list_item.xml","position":{"startLine":16}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

C:\Users\lucia.beltran\Desktop\Picho\Projects\Personal\improved-tribble\ImprovedTribble\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\debug\layout\task_list_item.xml:17: error: Error parsing XML: duplicate 

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.826 secs
```

My layout is as follows

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="task"
            type="com.pichardo.improvedtribble.models.Task" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And the layout of the binding file that gradle console says is like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:tag="layout/task_list_item_0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

I get which the duplicate attributes are, but I don't know why is crashing.

I read  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795682/error-using-databinding-in-android), but I don't have any like that on my build.gradle file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K or Cmd+K to properly format your source code chunks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to remove **android:layout_width** and  **android:layout_height="match_parent"** in **layout** tag

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="task"
            type="com.pichardo.improvedtribble.models.Task" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I hadn't figure it out, Thanks

Comment: Thats true, sometime its happens

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K or Cmd+K to properly format your source code chunks.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my redacted real code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="MyDTO"
            type="com.example.MyDTO"
        />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:mContext="com.example.MyActivity"
    >
```

All namespaces must be in outer layout tag. Any deletions did not help.

Comment: "All namespaces must be in outer layout tag" - that's right. Overwise your project will not compile.