# databinding does not exist: How to solve it?

Tags: android, data-binding

I'm working on an Android application with databinding but I've always next error:

> **Error:** Package `my.package.databinding` does not exist.

Here is my `build.gradle` on project level:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've also enabled binding in the `build.gradle` file on module level.

Now my question is, why occurs this error and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This problem occurs usually if your project does not compile. Android databinding should generate code in the named package, but it can't do that if the project doesn't compile in the first place.

To solve this, bring your project to a point where it compiles. If necessary, turn databinding off for this.

Comment: although my project compiled, without binding on, just disabling->compiling->re-enabling and compiling again worked for my project

Answer (score 4):

check out your xml files and comment any @{} you have used unless you actually have your data ready at hand. With no data, you'll bump into this error again and again and again.

Answer (score 4):

To see the error, just edit these lines of code in the app's build.gradle:

```
dataBinding {
enabled = false
}
```

In this way, the last error in your build console is the actual error. Because from the first to the penultimate error, they are all related to the non-generation of the data binding classes, precisely because we have disabled it.

Once you find the error you will enter again :

```
dataBinding {
enabled = true
}
```

Comment: this tag does not make any sense in my case

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue in a project of 4 modules in Android Studio 2.3, it is what @F43nd1r indicated, but want to document what I did to resolve this in my case.

One of the 4 modules had an older Android Support library in in the Gradle file for it, while the other 3 were current. This is what prevented the project from compiling properly and causing the databinding error.

The difficult part was that you don't know about this unless you open each `build.gradle` file and see if there is an error displayed. It did NOT show an error for it on compile.

Effectively I updated this area to the newer version number to match the other 3 module `build.gradle` files.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Defining the support library version in your project level build.gradle file would help keeping the modules in sync

Comment: In my case the project compiled, but the problem had not been resolved until the module 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' in build.gradle was updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

enabled the data binding in app build.gradle file. its worked

Answer (score 0):

Based on similar issues on SO, the reasons may not be related to android data binding, and instead due to incorrectly calling variables as in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33934991/5190134/) or some other factors like in this [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795682/error-using-databinding-in-android). You should provide more details if none of these links helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me doesn't work anything except one: **Renamed XML binding class**
What I tried before: 
off/on viewBinding
renaming folders
reinstalling modules
renaming modules

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the build folder for the project and submodules, making, rebuilding, etc etc etc, the only thing that worked for me was:

> create a new layout

I think there's something in the generator that gets messed up and that flushes it (totally guessing here)

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```