# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.example.example.databinding.ContentClassApplicationMyClass1Binding

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

I'm getting this error in android after updating the android studio from 3.0 to 3.1 and Gradle from 3.1 to 4.4.

How can I fix it?

It's working properly with Gradle 3.1 and android studio 3.0.

How can I get it to work?

Gradle app:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.13"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }




    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.6.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.8'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.8'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.8'
    compile 'com.github.twinkle942910:monthyearpicker:0.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.white:progressview:1.0.1'
    compile 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.8.1'
    implementation files('/libs/android-sdk-0.1.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'

    compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.1.8'


    compile 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Gradle-Project:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.31"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Gradle-wrapper.Properties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**Gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".Class_application_MyClass1"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_class_application_myclass_1">


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="25dp">


                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

                        android:id="@+id/name_TextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"

                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                            android:hint="Name"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

                        android:id="@+id/number_TextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/number"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                            android:hint="number"
                            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                            android:maxLength="10"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

                        android:id="@+id/classnumber_TextInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/class_number"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                            android:hint="class"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                            android:maxLength="15"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </ScrollView>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Class_application_MyClass1">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/fundscorner_blue"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/content_class_application_myclass_1"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center">

                <com.white.progressview.HorizontalProgressView
                    android:id="@+id/progress100"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:progress="25"
                    app:progressReachColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:progressTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:progressTextVisible="false"
                    android:minHeight="20dip"
                    android:maxHeight="20dip"

                    />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <include
            android:id="@+id/content_class_application_myclass_1"
            layout="@layout/content_class_application_myclass_1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/content_class_application_myclass_1"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button_stage1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/fundscorner_blue"
                android:text="Next"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

**In JAVA file:**

```
    ActivityClassApplicationMyClass1Binding binding;

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_class_application_myclass_1);



binding.name.settext("Name");
```

Comment: share gradle file

Comment: `Gradle from 3.1 to 4.4.` what does it mean ?

Comment: and also if you are using `27.1.0` change it to `27.0.2` cause `27.1.0` has some bugs !!

Comment: I'm using 27.0.2 itself.

Comment: I've added the gradle files

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I've added the files. Please check it out.

Comment: Do you have this class ? `ContentClassApplicationMyClass1Binding` inside the folder `databinding` ?

Comment: @jason change your targetSdkVersion 23 to 27

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I get the same error when I try 
        **targetSdkVersion 27**

Comment: @SantanuSur I don't have any folder called databinding. It is the id given to the layout inside the Activity.xml

Comment: can you post the layout and are you sure thats the only place you are using `ContentClassApplicationMyClass1Binding`

Comment: @SantanuSur 2 other layouts had that id. Thanks for that . BUt even after removing that I still get the same error!

Comment: I'm also face the issue like this so this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422477/unable-to-run-the-app-after-updated-the-playservice-version-as-12-0-0/49589288?noredirect=1#comment86426469_49589288

Comment: I'm also faced this issue so check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422477/unable-to-run-the-app-after-updated-the-playservice-version-as-12-0-0/49589288?noredirect=1#comment86426469_49589288)

Comment: @RajasekaranM Did not work :(  Btw, this code works fine with gradle plugin 3.1 but when  I upgrade to gradle plugin 4.4 it does not work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Its because of you class name or package name which use databinding. These class( which use databinding) have to start with capital word and packages start with lowercase.

Comment: "packages [must] start with lowercase" is a change from previous behavior, but it is indeed the case now

Comment: It worked, I dont understand why they do something like this!

Comment: It works, but sadly this breaks/deletes widgets. Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 16):

The reason for this error is, as Mehdi already stated in his answer, the capitalization in the Java package name of the binding and variable classes.

When further examining the logs, you can see that the error gets thrown at [ClassName.bestGuess(String)](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/javapoet-1.11.1/src/main/java/com/squareup/javapoet/ClassName.java#L178). The reason is that the package name of your bound classes, aka the ones in the `<variable>` field in your layout, contain uppercase characters in their package name. This causes the method to not be able to separate the Class name from the package name, and it throws an error.
*[to be honest, that's a rather poor behavior, but probably no better way exists (yet)]*

The same is true for the generated binding class, it also needs to be in a package that doesn't have any uppercase letters in it. As it uses your app package name by default, you have to change the java package name by adding the `class` property to the `<data>` field in your layout ([Read more here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#custom_binding_class_names)).

**Example:**

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data class="com.example.ExampleDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="example"
            type="com.example.ExampleClass" />
    </data>
</layout>
```

Comment: This is the great solution. Don't forget about applicationId in gradle too

Comment: It's not necessary to change the applicationId. I think this might cause problems if the app is on the store already.

Answer (score 2):

The Binding class name seems to be wrong. Can you try changing it from `ActivityClassApplicationMyClass1Binding` to `ActivityClassApplicationMyclass1Binding`

Comment: I've edited it but the point is that the same project works if I dont upgrade gradle plugin from 3.1 to 4.4

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, package names must start with a lowercase letter. My problem was that it started with an underscore "_" which was not allowed as well.

Answer (score 1):

you need to start all the class name with capital letter and package with small.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the type of variable in xml layout is empty.

Example :

```
   <variable
        name="onClickListener"
        type="" />
```

so in the above variable the type is empty this will lead to :

> couldn't make a guess for