# error after changing classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

Tags: android, gradle

My project is not building after changing the gradle link in gradle.project
If the value is -

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

then it works but if I change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'` then I get an error.

**Error**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.example.example.databinding.ContentClassApplicationMyClass1Binding
```

and error in **xml** at

```
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

and

```
 style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
```

How can I update the gradle and fix the issues?

Please refer to this link for more code:

[Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.example.example.databinding.ContentClassApplicationMyClass1Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528437/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-couldnt-make-a-guess-for-com-exa/49529522?noredirect=1#comment86071123_49529522)

Comment: share complete complete codes

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I've shared the link of the where I've shared the entire code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528437/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-couldnt-make-a-guess-for-com-exa/49529522?noredirect=1#comment86071123_49529522

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout use this as aparent in your xml file

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I'm still getting the same error!

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Can I share something over here which ca help you debug the issue?

Comment: Having same issue ( cannot resolve android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" ) with google-services:3.1.0. To confirm I remove classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'  and the error is gone.

Comment: @jason need logcats

Comment: have you read this :- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: @Puni I've removed  **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' ** and **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** but I'm still getting this error : **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.example.example.databinding.ContentClassApplicationMyClass1Binding**

Comment: @AbhinavGupta yes! I've been using it for the last 5 months and the code works when I don't update classpath from 3.0.1 to 3.1. ALso, I'm using databinding only to access the object and settext and stuff.

Comment: don't change use3.0.1

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Yup. I'm doing the same but I'm still unable to understand where the problem is!

Comment: without seeing your whole code I can not able to say anything because I had lot of confusion like this that's why i asked for teamviewer

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Hmm.. cool. I'll ping when I get free. Please let me know if you are free then!

Comment: okay iwill tell you

Comment: @json sorry I didn't make myself clear before, what I meant is I'm having same issue like you do and the problem is with google-services:3.1.0. removing google-services:3.1.0 is not the solution because I need those for adding firebase

Comment: @Puni Oh ok. Same here. Did you find any solution for the same?

Comment: @jason have you solved the issue? I am facing same

Comment: @johnsmithNope but someone mentioned to change all classnames to Capital letters

Comment: @johnsmith Please let me know if you solve it.