# Android data binding problem: "Cause: couldn't make a guess for"

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

i'm enabling data binding with adding

> dataBinding {
>           enabled = true
>       }

and

> kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'

in app level `build.gradle` file.

> apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

is added top of that.  project is based on kotlin .

here is my model:

```
    package ir.app.myapplication;



data class cisclass(val equRevId:String)
```

main Activity :

```
  val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        val user = cisclass("123")
        binding.setVariable(BR.cis, user)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
```

here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <data>

        <variable
            name="cis"
            type="ir.app.myapplication.cisclass" />
    </data>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">



                    <TextView
                        android:text="@{cis.equRevId}"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"

                        />


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</layout>
```

i will got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for ir.meedc.myapplication.cisclass
    at com.squareup.javapoet.Util.checkArgument(Util.java:64)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.bestGuess(ClassName.java:171)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.toTypeName(ext.kt:244)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.toTypeName(ext.kt:192)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.toTypeName(ext.kt:173)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter.createVariableFields(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:229)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter.access$createVariableFields(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:39)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter$createType$1.invoke(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:67)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter$createType$1.invoke(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:39)
    at android.databinding.tool.ext.Javapoet_extKt.classSpec(javapoet_ext.kt:39)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter.createType(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:63)
    at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutBinderWriter.write(BaseLayoutBinderWriter.kt:59)
    at android.databinding.tool.BaseDataBinder.generateAll(BaseDataBinder.kt:65)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$CodeGenerator.run(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:212)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$writeBaseClasses$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:52)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$writeBaseClasses$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
```

how can i fix that? whats the problem?

Comment: Maybe its due to the variable not being initialized and you set the variable after the activities layout is being drawn so android has to guess when inflating the textview on what text to render

Comment: thanks for comment, how can i fix this? load model in another method of mainActivity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50115802/7407809
your model class must be start with uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instead `binding.setVariable(BR.cis, user)` this `binding.setCis(user)`

Comment: i added this: ` val user = cisclass("123")
        binding.setVariable(BR.cis, user)
        binding.executePendingBindings()` but didnt work