# How to setup Data Binding in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-databinding

The Android Developers Guides for [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start) has the following code to enable data binding in `build.gradle` file in app module:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

But after after adding this code the Build Fails with this error:

```
error: package androidx.databinding does not exist
```

*Gradle Version : 4.0.1*

*Language : Kotlin*

Comment: Compile the project with "--debug and --stacktrace" for more informations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [databinding does not exist: How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440662/databinding-does-not-exist-how-to-solve-it)

Comment: Adding kotlin-kapt plugin did the work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Set up with data binding:

inside `Build.gradle(:app)`

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.5.1'
```

Bind your data in xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <data>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="DataModel" />
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="@{item.name}"/>// binding data from model

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

For more detail :[here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

Note: **sync gradle and clean & rebuild project**

Comment: dependency should be 

annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.5.1'